# None of my images are displaying when I run Android Studios.

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

This activity doesn't open my images at all however the text still opens. I tried both .png and .jpg. I have also tried @drawable still no result.

**Java code**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_images);
}
```

**xml script**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TextView
    android:text="JUST WORK!!!"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display2"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="58dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="177dp" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="120dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: use can use android:src = "@drawable/yourimage"

Comment: Mind taking down your only-useful-for-you question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks okay.

Try adding your image in your drawable folder.

And add,

android:src="@drawable/yourimage"

in your ImageView XML components.